# Javascript loops

Tags: javascript, loops

Im confused about JavaScript loop types.

## for loop

I learned that this loop looping until condition isn't false. If it false on first try it will never run.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
   console.log(i);
}
```

## while

It runs loop until condition isn't false. If it is false on first try, loop never starts.

```
var n = 8;

while (n < 9) {
  n++;
  console.log(n)
}
```

But i is 8 and n resulting into 9

questions:

- In for loop is condition true even if i = 8 - 8 is less than 9 so loop should increase i at number 9.
- Descricption of this two loops are pretty much the same whats the diference between them?

Comment: note that `++` sets the incremented value _after_ reflecting the current value, so when the for loop conditional runs, `i` is still 8, but then when it gets to the loop body, it's 9. in your _while_ loop, if you logged `n++` instead of doing it the step before, you would see the same value as the while conditional.

Comment: To make them equal, the `n++` has to be moved after `console.log`. Obviously, `n` should start from 0 to have them start with the same values.

Answer (score 1):

You see a difference because the last expression of a `for` loop runs **after** each iteration.

That means the following codes are equivalent:

```js
for (var /* VariableDeclarationList */; /* Expression 1 */; /* Expression 2 */) {
  /* StatementList */
}
```

```js
var /* VariableDeclarationList */;
while (/* Expression 1 */) {
  /* StatementList */
  /* Expression 2 */
}
```

But when transforming to a `while` loop, you placed the expression `n++` before the statements.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/510e3c1a3011b8fa25005255:

> For Loops allow you to run through the loop when you know how many
>   times you'd like it to run through the problem such as `for (var i; i
>   < 10; i++);` this will continually increase i untill that condition
>   returns false, any number can replace the 10 even a variable. but it
>   will quit once the condition is no longer being met. This is best used
>   again for loops that you know how when they should stop.
>
> While Loops allow you a little more flexability in what you put in it,
>   and when it will stop such as `while ( i < 10)` you can also substitue
>   in a boolean(true/false) for 10 as well as many other types of
>   varibles.
>
> The key difference between the two is organization between them, if
>   you were going to increase to 10 it'd be a lot cleaner and more
>   readable to use a for statement, but on the other hand if you were to
>   use an existing variable in your program in your loop parameters it'd
>   be cleaner to just wright a while loop. In the For loop you MUST
>   create a new variable, thats not true for the While loop.

Comment: See [this post](https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/510e3c1a3011b8fa25005255)

Comment: Last statement is not exactly true - for example `for(;;)` and `while(i = 5)` are valid loops ;)